# Proving two equations using multinomial coefficients.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, multinomial-coefficients

> Use the fact that multinomial coefficients are non-negative integers
>   to prove that (a) $(2n)!$ is divisible by $2^n$ (and that for n >= 2
>   the quotient is even) and (b) $(n^2!)!$ is divisible by $(n!)^{n+1}$

By "divisible by" the problem means evenly divide.

I have done similar problems to these using regular induction (although they did not have a variable in the denominator). I am not sure how to do these using multinomial coefficients. How do I start these two problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

- What is $$\binom{2n}{\underbrace{2,\ldots,2}_n}$$ when expressed in terms of factorials? For the second part of (a) try to cancel all of the factors in the denominator.
- Is there an integer $m$ that makes $$\binom{n^2!}{\underbrace{n!,\ldots,n!}_{n+1},m}$$ a multinomial coefficient? What is that coefficient when expressed in terms of factorials?

Comment: For the first point ${2n} \choose {2,...,2}$ would be ${2n!} / {2_1!2_2!...2_n!}$, correct? Since 2! is just 2, the denominator becomes $2^n$?

Comment: @Qwurticus: Yes, that’s correct, except that you need parentheses in the numerator: $(2n)!$, not $2n!$. The latter is $2\cdot n!$.

Comment: For the second point, why do I need to add $m$? Is the answer not similar to what I wrote for point one above, with ${n^2!} \choose {n_1!, n_2!, ... , n_{n+1}!}$ equaling $(n^2!)! / ((n!)^{n+1})$?

Comment: @Qwurticus: $(n+1)n!\ne n^2!$, so you don’t have a multinomial coefficient until you add an appropriate $(n+2)$-nd number on the bottom.